# Функциональный объект

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Что такое функциональный объект?

Comment: если не отвечу загребут в армию хелп!!!

Comment: Ну там не так уж плохо, и не так уж и страшно ;-)

Comment: @Grundy модеш ответить?

Comment: Это очень хорошо что загребут!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов чего хорошего???

Comment: [Википедия: _В C++ функциональный объект создаётся с помощью класса, у которого перегружен operator():_](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82#C.2B.2B)

Comment: @Grundy я читал это, как он создаеться понятно а что это такое воще?

Comment: на английском понятнее :-) _In C++, a function object may be used instead of an ordinary function by defining a class that overloads the function call operator by defining an operator() member function._ Это объект который может быть использоваться как функция

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @Kolя вы, может, подумаете о том, что учиться лучше, чем не учиться. И еще вы избавите этот сайт от своих вопросов вида "Я ничего не учил, но очень надо X". Также вы своим примером покажете остальным, что учиться - хорошо.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, это точно мне адресовалось? :-D

Comment: @Grundy Простите, как-то я все не могу проснуться :-(

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, но я все равно подумал что _учиться лучше, чем не учиться_ :-D и даже избавил _этот сайт от своих вопросов вида "Я ничего не учил, но очень надо X"_, вот только с примером не получается пока :-D

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Интересно отметить, что, строго говоря, в стандарте C++ не используется термин *функциональный объект*, то есть термин *functional object*. Есть термин *function object*.

Я не знаю, являются ли эти термины эквивалентными с точки зрения английской грамматики.:)

Я буду использовать термин объект функции. Проще говоря, этот термин означает объект класса, который имеет оператор вызова функции и может быть использован там, где используется постфиксное выражения вызова функции.

Из стандарта C++ (20.9 Function objects)

> 1 A function object type is an object type (3.9) that can be the type
>   of the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2, 13.3.1.1).231 A
>   function object is an object of a function object type. In the places
>   where one would expect to pass a pointer to a function to an
>   algorithmic template (Clause 25), the interface is specified to accept
>   a function object. This not only makes algorithmic templates work with
>   pointers to functions, but also enables them to work with arbitrary
>   function objects.

Наиболее известный представитель объекта функции - это лямбда выражения.

Вот демонстрационная программа. В первом цикле вызывается глобальная функция `::IsEven`, а во втором цикле вызывается объект функции - локальное лямбда выражение с тем же именем `IsEven`, которое имеет неявный оператор вызова функции. Объявление лямбда выражение скрывает имя глобальной функции.

```
#include <iostream>

bool IsEven( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; }

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( int x : a )
    {
        std::cout << x 
                  << " is " << ( IsEven( x ) ? "even" : "odd" ) << " number"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto IsEven = []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; };

    for ( int x : a )
    {
        std::cout << x 
                  << " is " << ( IsEven( x ) ? "even" : "odd" ) << " number"
                  << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
0 is even number
1 is odd number
2 is even number
3 is odd number
4 is even number
5 is odd number
6 is even number
7 is odd number
8 is even number
9 is odd number

0 is even number
1 is odd number
2 is even number
3 is odd number
4 is even number
5 is odd number
6 is even number
7 is odd number
8 is even number
9 is odd number
```

Вместо лямбда выражения вы могли бы определить свой функциональный объект. Например, вы можете заменить в демонстрационной программе объявление

```
auto IsEven = []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; };
```

на

```
struct
{
    bool operator ()( int x ) const { return x % 2 == 0; }
} IsEven;
```

и результат работы программы был бы тем же самым.
 В этом последнем объявлении определяется объект с именем `IsEven` безымянной структуры, которая содержит определение оператора вызова функции.